# Assigning default value to snowflake stored procedure arguments

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to have default values in arguments of Stored procedures of Snowflake. For the below example, I am getting error. Please help

syntax error line 1 at position 53 unexpected ''test''.

```
create or replace procedure test(arg1 string default 'test') 
returns string not null
language sql
as
$$
begin
return arg1;
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: Snowflake does not allow that so far. But you can use overloading for that and define another procedure with no arguments (or minus the argument for which default needs to be set) and declare a variable with default inside overloaded procedure body. So when a call is made without that argument overloaded procedure will be called with default variable set inside body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be providing `NULL` as value and handle it at the begining of the stored procedure with `COALSESCE`:

```
create or replace procedure test(arg1 string) 
returns string not null
language sql
as
$$
begin
   arg1 := COALESCE(arg1, 'test');

   return arg1;
end;
$$;


CALL test(NULL);
-- test
```

Answer (score 4):

Snowflake's procedures applies polymorphism instead of using default value. This solution is when you do not want to call sp like func1(Null)

For example (sql scripting):

```
create or replace procedure func1(arg1 varchar, arg2 varchar)
...

create or replace procedure func1(arg1 varchar)
... 
call func1(arg1 , 'some-default-value')
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting a default value/values as arguments directly in Stored procedures is not available in Snowflake currently

The below link can be referred for the allowed syntax in Stored Procedures
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure.html#syntax

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now to use default parameters. [See](https://medium.com/@infernoaudio/snowflake-procedure-default-parameter-values-24680dcf569f)

For example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ST_DEMO_DB.RAW_DATA.USP_EVT_LOG("EVT_TYPE" VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL, "EVT_DESC" VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TBL_EVT_LOG(EVT_TYPE,EVT_DESC)
    VALUES(COALESCE(:EVT_TYPE,'INFO'),:EVT_DESC);
    RETURN TRUE;
END
$$;
```